# Creating a CSS based horizontal dropdown menu with a horizontal sub nav

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a css horizontal drop down menu that will show the children in a horizontal subnav.  What I have so far is:  (this is incomplete but I am stuck)

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li class="top"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="top">
            <a href="/company/">About</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=2') ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
           <li class="top">
    <a href="/">Services</a>
<ul class="sub">
                   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=5') ?>
                </ul>
    </li>
           <li class="top">
<a href="/">Projects</a>
<ul class="sub">
                   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=7') ?>
                </ul>
</li>
           <li class="top">
<a href="/">Team</a>

<ul class="sub">
                   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=10') ?>
                </ul>
</li>
           </ul>
```

and the css:

```
.menu {padding:50px 0 0; list-style:none; line-height:1; width:400px;}
.menu li.top {display:block; float:left; position:relative; padding:0 17px 0 0;}
.menu li a.top_link {display:block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:33px; color:#bbb; 

text-decoration:none; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; padding:0 0 0 12px; 

cursor:pointer;}
.menu li a.top_link span {float:left; font-weight:bold; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 

12px; height:40px;}
.menu li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; 

height:40px; background:url(images/down.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span.down {background:url(images/button4a.gif) no-repeat right 

top;}

.menu li:hover > a.top_link {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span.down {background:url(images/button4a.gif) no-repeat right 

top;}

.menu table {border-collapse:collapse; width:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:0; 

left:0;}

.menu a:hover {visibility:visible;}
.menu li:hover {position:relative; z-index:200;}

.menu ul, 
.menu :hover ul ul, 
.menu :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-

9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

.menu :hover ul.sub {left:2px; top:20px; right:2px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0;  

white-space:nowrap; width:200px; height:auto;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li {display:block; height:20px; position:relative; float:left; 

width:250px;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a {float:right;font-weight:normal;display:block; font-size:11px;  

color:#000; text-decoration:none;}

.menu :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul
{left:90px; top:-4px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0; border:1px solid 999999; white-

space:nowrap; width:93px; z-index:200; height:auto;}
```

I really need some help I can not get this to work at all and need to running ASAP!

Rendered HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li class="top"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="top">
            <a href="/company/">About</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                   <li class="page_item page-item-33"><a href="http://localhost/cva/?page_id=33" title="Why CVA?">Why CVA?</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
           <li class="top">
    <a href="/">Services</a>
<ul class="sub">
                                   </ul>
    </li>
           <li class="top">
<a href="/">Projects</a>

<ul class="sub">
                                   </ul>
</li>
           <li class="top">
<a href="/">Team</a>

<ul class="sub">
                   <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/cva/?page_id=19" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
           </ul>
```

Comment: Can you describe what's not working a little?

Comment: the dropdown is not centering under the list...what I want is the dropdown to span the length of the top nav and then have the pages listed across

Comment: give us some rendered html to test with ..

Comment: rendered html has been added. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing this mess, here's a simple example you can use and apply:

HTML

```
<div class='menu'>
  <a href=''>One</a><a href=''>Two</a><a href=''>Three</a>
</div>

<div class='menu'>
  <a href=''>One</a><a href=''>Two</a>
</div>

<div class='menu'>
  <a href=''>One</a><a href=''>Two</a><a href=''>Three</a><a href=''>Four</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .menu       { float:left; line-height:20px; border:1px solid black; height:20px;  
               overflow:hidden; margin-right:10px; }
 .menu a     { display:block }
 .menu:hover { height:auto; }
```

Doesn't look good, but it works.  You can style it to look beautiful later.  (Don't forget the `doctype` to enable `:hover`.)

// Edit

Sorry just noticed the 'horizontal' part.  This is a vertical dropper.  Will leave it up though just in case it helps you.